# Is there a way to struct a Firestore fields(same name) with arrays and show each array element from each field in TableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a IOS app and I want to show the array Strings from all document fields in table view.

this is my struct for the array.

```
struct Test{
    var car: Array<String>


    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "car":car
        ]
    }


}

extension Test{
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
            guard let car = dictionary["car"] as? Array<String>
            else { return nil }

        self.init(car:car)
    }
}
```

This is my code for fetching the data.

```
func loadData(){

        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        db.collection("test").getDocuments(){
            querySnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }else{
                self.testArray = querySnapshot!.documents.compactMap({Test(dictionary: $0.data())})
                print(self.testArray)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

And this my tableView code.

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return testArray.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        let item = testArray[indexPath.row].car[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel!.text = ("\(item)")

        return cell
```

Everything seems fine but when run the app, the tableview shows the [0] from the 1st document in the first line, the [1] from the 2nd document in the second line etc. I want to show the whole array from first document then the whole array from 2nd document etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need multiple sections

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return testArray.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return testArray[section].car.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)   
    cell.textLabel!.text = testArray[indexPath.section].car[indexPath.row] 
    return cell
 }
```